# Injecting a bean to use in Controllers throughout the application

Tags: spring, servlets, dependency-injection, controller

I'm using spring mvc 3.1.x and jets3t.
I have a DataAccessObject that i instantiate as a Singleton bean..

I managed to get it working through extending the applicationcontextloader class and adding it to the web.xml

**EDIT:**

I changed my method, I tried inject and autowired but it's not suitable for my needs.
What I've done was to implement ApplicationContextAware and set it up as a bean, in the code I use it as follows:

```java
ApplicationContext ctx = BannerApplicationContext.getApplicationContext();
BannerGenericDAO bdao = (BannerGenericDAO) ctx.getBean("dao");
```

I'm new to Spring and in general the servlet world..
Questions are:

1. what's the best way of doing this? Is this considered a "best-practice"?
2. How do you inject an object, keeping other method fields that are not supplied by autowiring?
3. How do you get an object to be used throughout the entire application?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You could use annotations in your controller.

```
@Controller
public class MyController{

  @Autowired  // or @Inject, which is more JEEish (JSR330).
  private SomeDao daoService;

}
```

Given "SomeDao" is the type of your singleton DAO, of course.